# string sanitization to support special characters such as ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú, etc

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently using this script to sanitize a block of text...

```
function rseo_sanitize($s) {
    $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+/", "", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
    return $result;
}
```

I'd like to add support for a collection of special characters such as ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú, etc

How can I integrate those (and the larger collection of spanish characters) into the preg_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/\pL+/u` to match all letter symbols in Unicode.

There is no separate plane for Spanish letters only in PCRE, but you could try:

```
 /[^\p{Latin}0-9'-]+/u
```

This includes everything from the ISO Latin-1 charset I believe. That encompasses other european languages, not just spanish. But otherwise you would really have to list the desired letters individually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `\w` along with the `u` modifier

Example:

```
/[^\w]+/u
```